# ¿Cómo correr dos o mas ciclos al mismo tiempo en C#?

Tags: c#

¿Cómo puedo correr dos o más ciclos `foreach` al mismo tiempo?

La idea es optimizar. Esto es un poco de lo que hee investigado:

1. Con el uso de `Task.Factory`

   ```
       var task_uno = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
       {
           foreach (var elementos in listado)
           {
               if (elementos =="se_cumple")
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("TRUE");
                   break;
               }
           }
        });          

       var task_dos = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
       {
           foreach (var elementos in listado2)
           {
              if (elementos =="se_cumple")
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("TRUE");
                   break;
               }
           }
       });
   ```
2. Con el uso de `Parallel.ForEach`

   ```
        Parallel.ForEach(listado, (elememtos) =>
       {
              if (elementos =="se_cumple")
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("TRUE");
                   break;
               }
       });
   ```

> Aún no entiendo su uso.

3. Con el uso de `Thread`

   ```
    Thread proceso = new Thread(correr_foreach);
    proceso.Start();
   ```
4. Usando `Async` and `Await`

> ¿Cuál es la idea, o qué es lo que se pretende lograr?

Listado es llenado desde la base de datos (1 millon registros) y cargado desde el inicio (`Load`) separo dicho arreglo con el uso de varios `foreach`, corro el proceso pero por lo que sé, corre un `foreach` al terminar continúa con el otro y así sucesivamente hasta terminar. Entonces la pregunta es:

**¿Puedo correr dos o mas ciclos al mismo tiempo?**

Si la respuesta es sí, ¿entonces si en un ciclo se cumple la condición puedo detener los restantes para que no continúe el proceso de búsqueda?

Comment: Hola Rastalovely. Aunque siento que la pregunta tiene potencial y suena interesante, la verdad es que no la entiendo bien. Tal vez si puedes modificar el código para que podamos correrlo también, así como una explicación mas detallada del comportamiento actual en constraste con el compartamiento deseado, esto ayudaría a aclarar lo que buscas.

Comment: Hola he editado mi respuesta, espero pueda ser reabierta... Saludos

Comment: Creo que puedes utilizar hilos, y que cuando uno de ellos acabe, matar el resto de hilos, si es lo que necesitas.

Comment: y puedes correr varios hilos al mismo tiempo?

Comment: Claro @Rastalovely

Comment: Hola Rastalovely. Te voy a ser franco, todavía no me parece muy clara la pregunta. Uno de los problemas es que no es claro que tipo de proceso haces dentro de los ciclos, y eso es muy importante para determinar la mejor forma de optimizar el código. La respuesta puede variar dependiendo de si el proceso usa mucho el CPU, o la red, o el disco duro, etc.. Se necesitaría un ejemplo mas concreto, en mi opinión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución consiste en usar el [mecanismo de cancelación de operaciones sincrónicas y asincrónicas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx) introducida en .NET 4. Lo que debes hacer es pasar la misma instancia de `CancellationToken` a todas las tareas que desees cancelar. Luego, en cada una de ellas tienes que evaluar cada cierto tiempo si se ha solicitado la cancelación llamando al método `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`, el cual lanza una excepción del tipo `OperationCancelledException` si ésta se ha producido.

```
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;

var task_uno = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
        foreach (var elementos in listado)
        {
            // Comprobamos cancelación
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            if (elementos =="se_cumple")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("TRUE");
                tokenSource.Cancel();  // Se cancelan todas las tareas
                break;
            }
        }
}, token);          

var task_dos = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
        foreach (var elementos in listado2)
        {
            // Comprobamos cancelación
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

           if (elementos =="se_cumple")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("TRUE");
                tokenSource.Cancel();  // Se cancelan todas las tareas 
                break;
            }
        }
}, token);
```

Luego, una forma elegante de controlar posibles excepciones, la cancelación de la tarea o simplemente para hacer algo más justo cuando termina la tarea sin incidentes es con una nueva tarea:

```
task_uno.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    // La tarea terminó sin incidentes
    if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
    {

    }
    // Se produjo una excepción no controlada distinta de OperationCancelledException
    else if (t.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
    {

    }
    // Se canceló la tarea
    else if (t.Status == TaskStatus.Canceled)
    {

    }
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, por tu respuesta pronto publicare algunos aportes. Saludos