# Correr dos metodos pero pero esperar solo uno

Tags: c#, ado.net, asynctask

Necesito ejecutar dos metodos

```
Metodo1();
Metodo2();
```

El primero se debe ejecutar normalmente luego de esto debo retornar a la interfaz y dejar en `background` el metodo 2 ya que este se demora un poco mas y no retorna nada a la interfaz.

el primer metodo hace lo siguiente

```
      var dbcmd = database.GetStoredProcCommand("App_SpProgramarCita");
                database.AddInParameter(dbcmd, "IdCita", DbType.Int32, idCita);
                database.AddInParameter(dbcmd, "IdUsuario", DbType.Int32, idUsuario);
                database.ExecuteScalar(dbcmd);
```

y el segundo envia un correo, mi idea era un metodo asyncrono pero el executescalar no tiene este tipo de manejo.

Comment: Has intentado algo?

Comment: si algo asi `var task1 = Task.Run(() => Schedule());
            var task2 = Task.Run(() => SendMailConfirmation());

            var tasks = new[] { task1, task2 };
            Task completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

         
            await completedTask;
` pero el segundo metodo necesita informacion del primero, entonces no deberian ser al mismo tiempo sino uno tras el otro

Comment: Te lanza algun error? Porque no lo puedes hacer asi?

Comment: No me lanza ningun error pero como te digo, se ejecutan las dos a la vez y en el segundo puede darme error porque aun no se ejecuta la primera accion.

Comment: Hace tiempo hice una pregunta similar espero te ayude https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/47312/c%C3%B3mo-correr-dos-o-mas-ciclos-al-mismo-tiempo-en-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ejecutando el metodo Schedule primero y luego en otro hilo ejecutas el metodo `SendMailConfirmation()`:

```
Schedule();
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{
     SendMailConfirmation();
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su aporte, pero la pregunta es como puedo hacer para salir del metodo cuando se ejecute el metodo schedule() y dejar SendMailConfirmation() en background

Comment: Aclarame algo, el metodo `Schedule()` lo quieres ejecutar en backgrond? Solo el metodo `SendMailConfirmation()`?

Comment: solo SendMailConfirmation(), el schedule() se ejecuta y vuelve

Comment: Para ponerte en contexto es un web service de agendamiento de citas, al hacer el scheduler() ya puede retornar una respuesta el ws es decir si si agendo o no agendo, despues de eso si puedo dejar en background el envio de correo ya que este no me retorna nada.

Comment: Mira la respusta actualizada y dime si es lo que esperas.

Comment: voy a hacer la prueba, pero una pregunta var task = Task.Factory.New(()=>{
     SendMailConfirmation();
}); esta tarea se ejecutaria en background o el metodo esperaria hasta que se termine ?

Comment: Se ejecuta en background.

Comment: gracias voy a probar

Comment: Y el metodo es `StartNew()`, no `New`. Lo escribi mal. Lo actualize en la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Funciono !